What is the right place to report Bugs of Ubuntu as a whole?
I downloaded the ISO image of Xubuntu 24.04 from
http://ftp.uni-kl.de/pub/linux/ubuntu-dvd/xubuntu/releases/24.04/release/
I checked the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg and the downloaded image. Everything was ok. I made an USB stick using usb-creator-gtk. I successfully booted a computer from this stick. But it started as an English version with a US keyboard layout. Up to before I was used to encounter questions about the keyboard layout and the target language for the system. They were left out.
To be sure that this part has not been left out deliberately, I repeated it all again with an ISO image from
https://de.cdimages.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/24.04/release/
hoping to obtain a localized version for Germany from there when "de." is at the beginning of the URL. This server also promises https service rather than http only as the one before: Unfortunately de.cdimages.ubuntu.com has wrong certificates. But I downloaded everything despite of it and first checked it as before. But still the same result when booting from it.
I encountered definitely two independent bugs in "Ubuntu as a whole" or its distribution process. I reported them on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug. But I received the automated answer:
"Thank you for taking the time to report this bug and helping to make Ubuntu better. It seems that your bug report is not filed about a specific source package though, rather it is just filed against Ubuntu in general. It is important that bug reports be filed about source packages so that people interested in the package can find the bugs about it. You can find some hints about determining what package your bug might be about at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage. You might also ask for help in the #ubuntu-bugs irc channel on Libera.chat.
To change the source package that this bug is filed about visit  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/2076379/+editstatus and add the package name in the text box next to the word Package."
As the automatic system found out, this is a bug of the whole ISO image, not one of any package (at least of none, which I can identify). On the other hand: Why didn't they add a category of bugs not related to a particular package, like the problems reported here?
What is the right place/category to report errors or bugs of Ubuntu in general or the ISO Image
or the preset configurations on the ISO image or the cdimages.ubuntu.com server, especially certificate bugs on it, or the security mechanisms in the delivery of ISO images, PPAs and so on?

The keyboard layout thing definitely isn't a bug in "Ubuntu as a whole" or "its distribution process". It's a bug in the installer, at best. As for the certificate error, this is the first time I'm even hearing of country-specific sub-domains for cdimage.ubuntu.com. Where did you even get that de.cdimages.ubuntu.com domain from? I can't find any mentions of it other than the bug report you filed. For this issue, I'm inclined to think there is no bug at all, but rather a case of PEBKAC.

Bug reports for Xubuntu 24.04's installer would go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-provision, I'd think since https://github.com/Xubuntu/xubuntu-installer says they have migrated to that

The bug report you linked is filed against the whole Ubuntu Project and not an ISO image, or creation of the CD images (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage for example).  However you mention certificates which are likely site related detail (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors shows official sites) and not the ISOs themselves...
